# What is wrong with my Dynamic DNS settings?

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns

I host my own website on a home iMac. The website is accessible from its local and remote IP addresses, but recently, the hostname stopped working because the DNS stopped updating.

- I have been having trouble with my ISP (BT, using Home Hub 5) anyway, so I checked the dns updater on my router and it tells me the username or password for dyndns is incorrect or says "no such hostname" or various other errors. I have checked all options several times

[image]

- Giving up with the router, I installed the Mac Dyn Updater, but my hostname doesn't show up there either. Out of curiosity, I registered another of my hosts with Dyn (but left it inactive and un-checked-out) and it **does** appear in the dyn updater.

[image]
[image]

How can I change the dns settings for the problem domain please? What else might I have missed?

When I go to add a domain, I'm given a list of settings, but I can't seem to edit these settings for an existing domain, do anybody know if they can be changed?

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, your old dyndns account doesn't function any more. Are you sure it is still valid?

Comment: Yes, the host is still marked as "Active" and doesn't expire until next year. (See second screenshot)

Comment: I thought the update client updates hosts, not zones? Can you paste the host service config as well and confirm the host you're trying to update is listed?

Comment: @JonKloske, `hosts, not zones`. That seems reasonable, but the updater is currently listing a zone, just not the right one. Regarding : `host service config` I can't find any settings other than "add dns entry" for my domain. When I first created the account, I was given a form (see edit) with more options. However don't seem to be able to edit these settings now, I can't find an option to do so.

Comment: I just made a test dns entry: " http://test.ebsters.co.uk " and pointed it to my public IP. The page loads fine, suggesting that there's not a problem with my dyndns account, though it still may be in the dyndns settings.